# Phalcon model without a table

Tags: phalcon

I have a phalcon app on my localhost that uses version 1.3.1 and I also have version 1.3.2 on a remote server. On my localhost version I have declared some models that don't have an associated database table and these work fine, I use them as custom classes that aggregate various other models. As soon as they are uploaded to the remote server on 1.3.2 I get error messages about the associated table not existing though. I've tried setting the getSource method to return '' or null but this doesn't work either. Am I missing something here? How should I go about creating a class that doesn't have an associated table?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious solution would be for your models to not extend Phalcon\Mvc\Model if you are not using  db tables. 
If you dont set table using setSource method, phalcon will try to find table with same name as model name. 
Perhaps on your localhost version you have such tables and on remote db structure is different.

Comment: There's not User table on my localhost. I extend model as my model does have relationships with some other tables.Creating a blank table on my remote server seems to fix the issue but it's a weird one. I upgraded phalcon locally and I still don't get the issue there. Must be another setting around errors that is causing it to fall over on my remote host. It's also more stringent on upper and lowercase class names on my remote host.I should note I'm on Windows locally but Linux remotely